# Java Comparator Issue (Compare twice)

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I have an array of objects called array and have 3 items in it, which are: **id**, **numAccess** and **numDelete** **(all in primitive int)**.
What I want to do:  `sort first by numAccess then by numDelete`.

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
     System.out.println("ID: " + array[i].id + " numAccess: " + array[i].numAccess + " numDelete: " + array[i].numDelete);
}

Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Process>(){
     public int compare(Process p1, Process p2) {
          Integer compr = Integer.valueOf(p1.numAccess).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.numAccess));
        
          if (compr != 0) {
               return compr;
          } 
        
          return Integer.valueOf(p1.numDelete).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.numDelete)); 
     }
});

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
      System.out.println("ID: " + array[i].id + " numAccess: " + array[i].numAccess + " numDelete: " + array[i].numDelete);
}
```

Let's say if  `before sort` is this:

```
ID: 1 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 8
ID: 2 numAccess: 4 numDelete: 15
ID: 3 numAccess: 7 numDelete: 9
ID: 4 numAccess: 13 numDelete: 5
ID: 5 numAccess: 9 numDelete: 13
ID: 6 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 6
```

Then `desired after sort` should be:

```
ID: 6 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 6
ID: 1 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 8
ID: 2 numAccess: 4 numDelete: 15
ID: 3 numAccess: 7 numDelete: 9
ID: 5 numAccess: 9 numDelete: 13
ID: 4 numAccess: 13 numDelete: 5
```

However, what I get is this:

```
ID: 0 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 0
ID: 0 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 0
ID: 0 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 0
ID: 6 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 6
ID: 1 numAccess: 0 numDelete: 8
ID: 2 numAccess: 4 numDelete: 15
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong. May I get some advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. That is, some code that I can copy and paste into my IDE and be able to run it to reproduce your output. e.g. you should show how you created the array, and the class from which the objects are created.

Comment: Arrays start at index 0, so you are not printing the first element. Sort will sort the entire array, but you only print up to index n, no matter what the size of the array is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only sort part of the array (from index 1 to n inclusive) you can use `Arrays.sort(array, 1, n+1, comparator);`

Also note that your comparator implementation is unnecessarily complex. You can replace

```
Integer compr = Integer.valueOf(p1.numAccess).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.numAccess));
```

with

```
int compr = Integer.compare(p1.numAccess, p2.numAccess));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 8, you can use method `Comparator::comparing` to start sorting on first field and then a chain of `Comparator::thenComparing` methods to choose the subsequent fields to sort on

```
Comparator<Process> processComparator = Comparator.comparing(Process::getNumAccess)
.thenComparing(Process::numDelete);
        Arrays.sort(array, processComparator);
```

Comment: Since the fields are primitive int, using `comparingInt` and `thenComparingInt` will avoid the boxing and unboxing of integers.

Comment: Also that does not help to sort correctly "empty" items where all fields are 0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the input array contains several "empty" `Process` values (with `ID == 0`), so sorting needs to be customized to put such values to the end of array, or the input array needs to be filtered to exclude such values.

1. Put to the end the values with `ID == 0`
   A method to customize process id for sorting needs to be implemented:

```java
// MyClass
public static int getIdForSorting(Process p) {
    return p.getId() == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 0;
}
```

Then it may be used in sorting:

```java
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator
    .comparingInt(MyClass::getIdForSorting)
    .thenComparingInt(Process::getNumAccess)
    .thenComparingInt(Process::getNumDelete)
);
```

When printing the array contents using `for` loop, indexing has to start from 0.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]); // assuming method `toString` overridden in Process
}
```

2. Use Stream API to filter out "empty" processes

```java
Process[] sortedArray = Arrays.stream(array)
      .filter(p -> p.getId() > 0)
      .sorted(Comparator
          .comparingInt(Process::getNumAccess)
          .thenComparingInt(Process::getNumDelete)
      )
      .toArray(Process[]::new);
```

Here "empty" values are truncated after sorting, so `for-each` loop may be used:

```java
for (Process process : sortedArray) {
    System.out.println(process); // assuming method `toString` overridden in Process
}
```

---

@ThomasKläger offered an [interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69324740/13279831) based on [`Arrays::sort(T[] arr, int from, int to, Comparator<T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-int-int-java.util.Comparator-) method to sort the array in range `[1..n+1]`.

In this case item[0] and the tail of the array remains unsorted.

---

Tests:

```java
Process[] array = {
    new Process(), new Process(1,  0,  8), new Process(2,  4, 15),
    new Process(3,  7,  9), new Process(4, 13,  5), new Process(5,  9, 13),
    new Process(6,  0,  6), new Process(), new Process()
};
// after sorting with getIdForSorting
ID: 6   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 6
ID: 1   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 8
ID: 2   numAccess: 4    numDelete: 15
ID: 3   numAccess: 7    numDelete: 9
ID: 5   numAccess: 9    numDelete: 13
ID: 4   numAccess: 13   numDelete: 5
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0

// after filtering/truncating
ID: 6   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 6
ID: 1   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 8
ID: 2   numAccess: 4    numDelete: 15
ID: 3   numAccess: 7    numDelete: 9
ID: 5   numAccess: 9    numDelete: 13
ID: 4   numAccess: 13   numDelete: 5

// after sorting the subrange
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0
ID: 6   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 6
ID: 1   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 8
ID: 2   numAccess: 4    numDelete: 15
ID: 3   numAccess: 7    numDelete: 9
ID: 5   numAccess: 9    numDelete: 13
ID: 4   numAccess: 13   numDelete: 5
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0
ID: 0   numAccess: 0    numDelete: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class has *accessors* for the fields, you can use [Comparator#comparing methods](https://javadevcentral.com/java-comparator-comparing) to simplify your comparator logic.

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(Array::getNumAccess)
            .thenComparingInt(Array::getNumDelete));
```

Also, note that array indices start at 0 and hence your *for* loop should be like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + array[i].id + " numAccess: " + array[i].numAccess + " numDelete: " + array[i].numDelete);
}
```